# Can't see assciations to photo.SE from my other SE accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am a little surprised to find the photo.SE association missing on my other SE ['`Related Accounts'` pages](https://superuser.com/users/263?tab=accounts#tab-top). However, I can see the association to all of them from my [photo.SE Related Accounts page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/163?tab=accounts#tab-top).

These accounts are clearly associated but photo does not show up on my other profiles, anyone know what's missing here?

<sup>am tagging this as a bug for now.</sup>

Comment: I can't see them for myself either, not even from other SE sites

Comment: It's the same for me, and I do see my webapps.SE account on my SO 'related accounts' page, and like you I can see all of my accounts (including other beta.SE sites) from photo.SE. I wonder if this would be best posted on meta.SO, as I'm not sure how well bugs will be picked up here.

Comment: Same here; photo.SE sees one more account than the others (which do not see photo.SE)